# Two-way fixed effects panel regression by group

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have searched a lot of question as to how I can successfully do this but to no avail. The closest I have come is this: [Panel regression by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912356/panel-regression-by-group) , but even that does not completely cover the scope of what I want.

I have a dataset containing financial data on multiple firms in different industries over a period of 11 years. Now I have successfully done two-way fixed effects regression over the entire dataset using:

```
plm(ROS ~ ELI + ELI*Pandemic + Growth + Assets,
               data = df,
               index = c("Year", "Firm"),
               model = "within",
               effect = "twoways")
```

And I have quite good results except they're not 100% what I was hoping for. Now I would like to do this same regression but grouped by the industries (NAICS) that the firms are in. This way I can take a deep dive into whether different industries have different results.

A sample of my dataset can be found below although I think that to successfully do this more data is required. If so I would happily send my entire dataset over. Basically, I have 46 industries (NAICS) each with multiple firms and 11 years of data per firm.

```
df <- structure(list(NAICS = c(315, 3151, 3152, 3153, 3154, 3155), 
Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), 
Firm = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
Assets = c(399.5, 674.42, 1289.57, 2216.97, 2691.89, 2566.8), 
Inventories = c(117.17, 187.41, 266.89, 426.94, 519.91, 546.8), 
Sales = c(803.34, 1302.25, 2181.73, 3310.84, 4371.47, 4712.1), 
Growth = c(0, -0.62, -0.68, -0.52, -0.32, -0.08), 
ROS = c(0.17, 0.19, 0.29, 0.3, 0.29, 0.25), 
ELI = c(0.856264428748774, 0.723379402777553, 0.958341156943977, 0.680567730897854, 0.790480861209701, 0.827279134948296), 
Pandemic = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I hope that it's clear enough.

Comment: So I can do it manually by creating different excel files for each industry and then running the script per data frame, but this is tedious and there has to be a better way to do it. Maybe in an IF loop, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Be sure to use the `index` argument correctly: the obvservational unit comes first, then the time index - seems like you mixed them up.

Comment: ad your question: is suggest to simply add industry fixed effects by including `+ factor(NAICS)` in your formula.