# New objects for table in regression loop

Tags: r, loops

I am new to R, and am trying to loop regressions by group. For my data I have 13 groups, and would like to create 13 objects--a regression result for each group, so I can put all the regression results in a table.
Here is what I have tried:

```
for (i in 1:13) {groupi = lm(Yvariable ~ Xvariables,
           data = dataset,
           subset = dataset$group== i )}
```

So that I would have 13 group'i' objects that are each a regression result to put into a table.
THANKS!

Comment: try one of the solutions from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796317/r-predict-glm-fit-on-each-column-in-data-frame-using-column-index-number/51810814#51810814

Comment: Split your data, then map `lm` over the different subsets to make a list: `values <- lapply(split(dataset, dataset$group), function(grp) {lm(yvar~xvars, data=grp)})`

Comment: see `lme4::lmList()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `by`, object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`, designed to subset data frames by factor(s) and run operations on the subsets. Often it can replace `split` + `lapply` for a more streamlined call:

```
reg_list <- by(dataset, dataset$group, function(sub)
                summary(lm(Yvariable ~ Xvariables,
                           data = sub)
                       )
              )
```

Please note the above only produces a named list of regression result summaries. Further work is needed for extraction of each model's estimates by extending `function`.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your problem right there is a specialised command for this: lmList from the nlme package. 
Try this:

```
    library(nlme)
    your.result.list <- lmList(Yvariable ~ Xvariables | group, data = dataset)
    your.result.list
```

The object `your.result.list` is of class `lmList` so it is a list with the 13 elements that you wanted to have as single objects. It has a generic print option which prints you a table of the coefficients into the console. So maybe this is already what you want?